# Flickering edge on jquery width animation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a horizontal accordion style slider that doesn't rely on fixed widths. My issues are:

1. 'flickering edge' on the right-hand list item during animation
2. (Depending on the max-width set for the slider) the last item in the slider is sometimes knocked below the rest of the slider.

My initial thoughts are that the added width value of all of the list items must always equal 100% during the animation, but I have no ideas about how to force this.

I have searched the web for similar issues with no luck so any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my simplified jquery (apologies for any obvious mistakes, i'm still learning):

```
(function($) {

$.fn.horizontalSlider = function(options) {

var defaults = {
  openWidth: 65, // Initial list item width
  delay: 500, // Delay before items open
  easing: 'linear' // Type of easing for animation
};

var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

return this.each(function() {

  // Variables          
  var listItems = $(this).children('li'); // Select children
  var articles = listItems.children('article'); // Select articles  
  var listNum = listItems.size();   // Count list items
  var openWidth = options.openWidth; // Width of open item
  var closedWidth = (100 - openWidth) / (listNum - 1); // Width of closed item

  // Close all but first item
  listItems.css({
    'width': closedWidth + '%', 
    'float': 'left',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  }).first().addClass('open').css({
    'width': openWidth + '%'
  });

  var articleWidth = listItems.first().width(); // Width of content hidden by item

  // Set width of articles within each item
  $(this).find('article').css({'width': articleWidth});

  listItems.mouseenter(function() {

  // Set variable for current list item
  var currentItem = $(this);

      if ( currentItem.hasClass('open') ) { /* Do nothing */ } 
      else {
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

          // Slide closed open list items
          listItems.removeClass('open')
          .animate({
            'width': closedWidth + '%'
          }, { duration: 800, easing: options.easing, queue: false });

          currentItem.addClass('open')
          .animate({
              'width': openWidth + '%'
            }, { duration: 800, 
              queue: false,
              easing: options.easing, 
              complete: function() { /* Callback function */ } 
            });
        }, options.delay);
     }
  });

  listItems.mouseleave(function() {
    if(window.hoverTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    };
  });       

});
};

})(jQuery);
```

My html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.horizontalSlider').horizontalSlider();
  });
</script>

<section>
  <ul class="horizontalSlider cf">
    <li>
      <article>
        <img src="image1" />
      </article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article>
        <img src="image2" />
      </article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article>
        <img src="image3" />
      </article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article>
        <img src="image4" />
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul><!-- /.horizontalSlider -->
</section>
```

and css:

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
section {display: block; max-width: 1000px; padding: 10px; margin: 60px auto; background: #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I had access to your actual page I can't replicate the flickering.  As far as the animating goes I've never had any luck animating two things at once.  I've always had to do one then the other.

Mainly whats happening is that the width when you try and open and close each element is exceeding the max-width and making it wrap.

I've got two suggestions I can give you.

The first is to set the padding to 0 on the section tag.  My example eliminated the last element jumping but you can see the other elements moving a little bit. Here's my example with your code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henesnarfel/HjL85/). JQuery animations don't play nice with padding and margin most of the time.

The second is to change both animate queue's to be true.  This will allow the open one to close and then after its done the hovered one will open.  Not ideal for what you are probably looking for but it works.